# How to save the values entered in a form to a list in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I want to retrive values from a view 'Gestion.ascx' and to save them in a list using button.

This is what I try but without any result:

```
The View Gestion :
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Anouar")) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" onclick="test();"/>Poste Initial<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final</div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Position)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PostePrecedentSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PosteSuivantSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>


        <div><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  /></div>

        </fieldset>
```

The Controller 'AnouarController' is the controller which populate the view 'Gestion' :

```
public class AnouarController : Controller
    {

         private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();


        //
        // GET: /Anouar/

         public ActionResult Gestion(FlowViewModel model)
         {

             model.YourGammeModel = new Gamme();
             return PartialView(model);

         }




         public ActionResult Save(Gamme gamme)
         {
             UserGammes.Add("currentUserID", gamme);

         }

    }
```

and Finaly the model FlowViewModel :

```
public class FlowViewModel 
{ 

[Key] 
public string IDv { get; set; } 
[NotMapped] 
public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; } 

public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; } 
public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; } 

public Gamme YourGammeModel { get; set; } 

public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; } 

public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; } 

public int SelectedPoste { get; set; } 

public int PostePrecedentSelected { get; set; } 
public int PosteSuivantSelected { get; set; } 
private static Dictionary<string, Gamme> userGammes; 

public static Dictionary<string, Gamme> UserGammes 
{ 
get 
{ 
if (userGammes == null) 
{ 
userGammes = new Dictionary<string, Gamme>(); 
} 
return userGammes; 
} 
} 

}
```

Comment: in the controller, did you check the `ModelState`. Is it valid. You can check using `ModelState.IsValid`. If it is invalid, you have an issue in model binding

Comment: @saravanan the controller is not complete as you see. Infact, UserGammes.Add("currentUserID", gamme); is underlined in Red. Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: no issues, you can just try to debug by using `return View()` and get to know what is happening.

Comment: @saravanan lol ok but how will I know that the save is success ?

Comment: I thought that you were reporting about not being able to do model binding.

Comment: no i am just want to record values retrieved from the FORM in a LIST. It the same idea of the Insert in Database but this is not in the base